# Opening OSM bbox file in gzip

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I have downloaded the following OSM bbox file: https://overpass-api.de/api/map?bbox=-105.32,39.95,-105.2,40.08

And want to use it to find all points of interests. My teacher have given me the following code in Python but I cannot make it work:

```
import pandas as pd
import gzip
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

## Functions
def pick_from_dict(d, keys):
    return {key: d[key] for key in keys}
def merge_dicts(d1, d2):
    return dict(set(d1.items() | set(d2.items())))
def get_amenity(node):
    return {'amenity': next(filter(lambda child: child.attrib.get('k') == 'amenity', node)).attrib['v']}
def has_amenity_child(node):
    return any(child.attrib.get('k') == 'amenity' for child in node)
def get_pois(root):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        map(lambda node: merge_dicts(get_amenity(node), pick_from_dict(node.attrib, ['lat', 'lon', 'timestamp'])),
            filter(has_amenity_child, root.findall('node')))
    ).assign(timestamp=lambda d: pd.to_datetime(d.timestamp))\
    .sort_values(by='amenity')\
    .assign(lat=lambda df: df.lat.astype(float), lon=lambda df: df.lon.astype(float))


## Load data
df_pois = get_pois(ET.parse(gzip.open('map.xml.gz', 'rb')).getroot())
df_pois.head()
```

From the code I can see that he is using an xml.gz file. However when I download the bbox file the file format is imply "File". How can I convert the file and do I need to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file downloaded from Overpass API is a simple XML file (`.xml`). So either compress it using gzip so that it becomes `.xml.gz`. Or remove the `gzip.open()` from your code and simply use `ET.parse('map.xml')`.